# Bag with 50 balls, 7 different colors. Find probabilities when we pick out 8 without putting them back.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There's a bag with 50 balls. 17 white, 10 red, 7 orange, 3 purples 5 yellow, 2 blue and 6 green. We pick 8 balls randomly without putting them back. 
First, what is the probability of picking exactly 3 white?
Second, what is the probability of picking exactly 3 white, 2 red, 1 blue, and 2 green?

I thought of combinotorics to try to solve this but I'm not sure if I'm close or just completely off base. For the first question I had $\frac{\binom{8}{3} \binom{17}{1} \binom{16}{1} \binom{15}{1} \binom{33}{5}} {\binom{50}{8}}$ The top would be the ways to arrange 3 balls among 8 balls, then picking 1 white ball out of 17, then 1 out of 16, then 1 out of  15, then picking 5 balls out of the possible 33 that arent white.

Finally everything divided by the total number of ways to pick 8 balls from 50. I didn't bother trying for question 2 if I hadn't grasped question 1. Am I on the right track here?

Thanks

Comment: The top of the fraction should be the amount of ways to pick exactly 3 white balls and 5 non-white balls. This is just the amount of ways to pick 3 white balls out of a pile of 17 times the amount of ways to pick 5 non-white balls out of a pile of 33.

Comment: I'm not sure how those two differ. "This is just the amount of ways to pick 3 white balls out of a pile of 17 times the amount of ways to pick 5 non-white balls out of a pile of 33" , isn't this "the amount of ways to pick exactly 3 white balls and 5 non-white balls" ? I suppose I'm missing something here, I thought this was how to do it.

Comment: That was my point, that these are equal. Moreover, it is not equal to what you wrote on the top of the fraction. Notice, for example, that the fact that we pick 8 balls in total is irrelevant, except for the fact that 3+5=8, so the 8 choose 3 term should not be there.

Comment: @SmileyCraft Right, I understand what you were saying now. By saying I pick 3 out of 17 and 5 out of 33, there is no need to say I'm picking 3 in 8. So the top should just be (17 nCr 3)*(33 nCr 5) ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @SmileyCraft And for the next question, I would simply do what I did for the white ball, but do it for every color mentioned? Like (17 nCr 3)*(10 nCr 2)*(2 nCr 1)*(6 nCr 2) for the top fraction I presume? The divide by the same thing

Comment: Very good. That is indeed the way to solve this.